# IntelliJ IDEA 15 not able to import maven projects

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

Here are some of the messages from my IDEA log file. It appears that it is not able to connect to some maven service on localhost. This used to work just fine for me with 14.

```
classworlds-2.5.1.jar" org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.RemoteMavenServer 
2016-01-27 20:03:44,054 [ 318261]   INFO - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - Port/ID: 44435/Maven32ServerImplaa933e0f 
2016-01-27 20:04:59,912 [ 394119]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - The cook failed to start due to java.net.ConnectException: Operation timed out 
2016-01-27 20:05:44,776 [ 438983]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - java.rmi.NotBoundException: _DEAD_HAND_ 
2016-01-27 20:05:44,776 [ 438983]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl.lookup(RegistryImpl.java:166) 
2016-01-27 20:05:44,776 [ 438983]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - at com.intellij.execution.rmi.RemoteServer.start(RemoteServer.java:88) 
2016-01-27 20:05:44,776 [ 438983]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.RemoteMavenServer.main(RemoteMavenServer.java:22) 
2016-01-27 20:06:15,111 [ 469318]   WARN -      #org.jetbrains.idea.maven - Cannot open index /Users/xxxxx/Library/Caches/IdeaIC15/Maven/Indices/Index0 
org.jetbrains.idea.maven.indices.MavenIndexException: Cannot open index /Users/xxxxx/Library/Caches/IdeaIC15/Maven/Indices/Index0
```

Update - 1

Found this bug report -> https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-147234 which says we should upgrade maven to atleast 3.3.3 I did but I am still seeing the same problem

Comment: Maybe try [cleaning your system cache](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/cleaning-system-cache.html)?

Comment: I followed this answer on the IntelliJ site https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-64132#comment=27-380070 I mucked around with my /etc/hosts file removing spaces/tabs and such and it seems to have helped

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's related with /etc/hosts as @MoizRaja mentioned. I suggest to try commenting everything in /etc/hosts and just leave

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
```